# Active Storage with Amazon S3 not saving with filename specified but using file key instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I am having an issue with Active Storage. When I upload to Amazon S3, instead of saving the file inside the bucket with the original name like `myfile.zip` it is saving it as the `key` which is associated with that file. So in Cyberduck I am seeing something like this: `5YE1aJQuFYyWNr6BSHxhQ48t`. Without any file extension.

I am not sure if there is some setting in Rails 5 or whether it is within Amazon S3 but I have spent hours Googling around to figure out why this is happening.

Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Best regards,
Andrew

Comment: I haven't worked with Cyberduck, but if you write a script to download files from a bucket, then [Ruby's File class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/File.html) and [FileUtils module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html) module can be helpful for translating keys to file paths and for capturing the file name.

Comment: Many thanks @GinnieHench, this is for the download side of things, but I was just wondering whether it was possible to change the actual filename inside the S3 bucket itself. To be the original filename.

Comment: @Drew, it isn’t.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design, from ActiveStorage. The file is stored by it's key and without extension on S3, but when the URL is generated by ActiveStorage, the [disposition and filename are set](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service/s3_service.rb#L70).

```
def url(key, expires_in:, filename:, disposition:, content_type:)
  instrument :url, key: key do |payload|
    generated_url = object_for(key).presigned_url :get, expires_in: expires_in.to_i,
      response_content_disposition: content_disposition_with(type: disposition, filename: filename),
      response_content_type: content_type

    payload[:url] = generated_url

    generated_url
  end
```

end

This is probably done to avoid filename escaping issues that you'd run into otherwise.

You can read more about the `Content-Disposition` headers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

Comment: Wow I had no idea! Thanks so much! I did wonder if that was by design!

Comment: Using key without file extension breaks caching with cloudflare cdn (since cloudflare uses a whitelist of extensions to cache files).

Answer (score 5):

You can still reference the name with filename accessor.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo
  ...
end

filename = User.first.photo.filename
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to have a custom filename on S3, you should update both `blob.key` and the name on S3.

Active storage uploads images on S3 using `blob.key` as remote image path and name.

For my usage, I only changed the name for 'images variants' with a Monkey Patch that allows to generate a `key` terminating by the `filename` :

`config/initializers/active_storate_variant.rb` :

```
ActiveStorage::Variant.class_eval do
  def key
    "variants/#{blob.key}/#{Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(variation.key)}/#{filename}"
  end
end
```

So when I need the public url for an image variant, I just call `image.url('400x400')`

This is how my Image model is customized :

```rb
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  has_one_attached :picture

  SIZES = { '400x400' => '400x400' }

  def url(size)
    return "https://placehold.it/#{size}" unless picture.attached?

    'https://my_s3_subdomain.amazonaws.com/' +
        picture.variant(resize: SIZES[size]).processed.key
  end

  ...

end
```

If someone has a better way to do that, I would be happy to see it :)