# Active Storage - Original Filename Extension with URL or Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have this model...

```
class TlfTest < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :tlf
end
```

I'm trying to upload this file with extension `.tlf` using Active Storage to be used with a service object, but the file gets stored with a long string without the file extension which is then not recognizable to the service object.

Original filename: `layout.tlf`

Saved file (blob) in local storage: `99y4ytvs1vi0x3zka9vgqde38w15`

If I use `ActiveStorage::Blob.service.path_for(tlf_test.tlf.key)` for the path to the file in my service object, the file isn't found. However, if I manually rename the file in the storage path and add the `.tlf` extension, it works fine.

I tried `url_for` which seems to have the extension, but ultimately redirects to the blob which doesn't, and still doesn't work. Is there something else I can do to keep the original file extension?

Comment: Can I have a look at the controller code?

Comment: [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640231/active-storage-with-amazon-s3-not-saving-with-filename-specified-but-using-file?rq=1 ]
Also have a look at this, might help.